# Probability density function transformation

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference

Probability density function of f is given as a uniform distribution, f(x)=1 and I need to find the probability distribution function of Y=X-X^2.

What I have done so far is that I found the inverse image of Y=X-X^2. Which is g^-1= 1/2 + sqrt(1/4-y). After this, I need to find probability density function of Y, which is fy(y)=fx(g^-1(y))*(derivative of g^-1(y).

My problem starts here, because derivative of g^-1(y) is not defined when y is in between 0 and 1/4. Plus, when I plot the probability density function of y that I found by myself doesn't make any sense to me. Because when I integrate the probability density function of fy(y) I cannot find 1.

I'd really appreciate any help to determine boundaries of fy(y) and/or any suggestions about how to find the inverse image of Y=X-X^2.

Sorry about the messy explanation.

Comment: What is the domain over which $f(x) = 1$?

Comment: Sorry. X is uniformly distributed over interval [0,1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume that $X$ is uniformly distributed over interval $\left[0,1\right]$.

Under that condition $X^{2}-X$ a.s. takes values in $\left[-\frac{1}{4},0\right]$
and for $x\in\left[-\frac{1}{4},0\right]$ we find: $$X^{2}-X\leq x\iff\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\left(1+4x\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\leq X\leq\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\left(1+4x\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$
Denoting the CDF of $X^{2}-X$ by $F$ we find $F\left(x\right)=\left(1+4x\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$
for $x\in\left[-\frac{1}{4},0\right]$.

We can find the PDF of $X^{2}-X$  by taking the derivative of $F$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The problem is this actually, maybe I am mistaken in a way but when I take the derivative of F, shouldn't this derivative be defined when x∈[−1/4,0]? Derivative of F doesn't satisfy this when x=-1/4 I guess.

Comment: Essential for a PDF $f$ connected with a CDF $F$ is that it is a
measurable function that satisfies $F\left(x\right)=\int_{-\infty}^{x}f\left(t\right)dt$.
Mostly it is also demanded that $f$ is non-negative. There are always
lots of options for the PDF. Mostly one (or two) of them 'jumps out'
as favourite. Here it is convenient to take $f\left(x\right)=2\left(1+4x\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$
for $x\in\left(-\frac{1}{4},0\right)$ (or for $x\in\left(-\frac{1}{4},0\right]$)
and $f\left(x\right)=0$ on the complement of that open interval (or
half-open interval).